# How to store a text file into a vector (C++)

Tags: c++, file, vector

I need help storing text from a text file into a vector.

The text file is called "names.txt" and it has the following data

```
salman
mahmoud
ahmad
ghadeer
raghad
abdullah
faisal
```

The text below is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<string> STRING;
    ifstream infile;

    infile.open ("names.txt");

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        getline (infile, STRING[i]);
        cout << STRING[i];
    }

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Everytime I run the program, I get the following error message

[image: Visual Studio Error Message]

Comment: 1) Dont' name your variable "STRING".  By convention, all-uppercase names are reserved for C/C++ macos.  2) Read about [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  In particular, read about `v.push_back(line);`  3) In this case, you forgot to initialize the size.  *BUT YOU SHOULDN'T HARD CODE "7".  That defeats the whole purpose of having a variable length "vector" :(!!!!

Comment: Try `vector<string> STRING(7);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared your vector, but you did not set its size.

You can:

- Either declare a vector with a specific size
- or simply use `push_back()` function like below:

.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    string temp; // temporal variable - just a place holder
    getline (infile, temp); // get line 
    MyVector.push_back(temp); // add it to the vector (add to the end of it)
}
```

Comment: Very good reply.  One additional suggestion: the OP should eliminate `for (i=0; i < 7; i++)` and substitute `while (getline (infile, temp) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access elements of the vector which are not created.
When you call

```
vector<string> STRING
```

it creates a vector capable of storing strings, but not having any.
So, when you a trying to access one of them with STRING[i], it says that you are trying to access non-existing element.

Possible solution: before the loop call

```
STRING.resize(7);
```

It'll allocate memory for 7 empty strings and then this loop will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<string> STR;
    ifstream infile;

    infile.open ("names.txt");

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        string st;
        getline (infile, st);
        STR.push_back(st);
        cout << STR[i] << endl;
    }

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to write to an empty vector. This can easily be fixed by simply change:

```
vector<string> STRING;
```

to:

```
vector<string> STRING(7);
```

However, you should change the name of the vector to something like:

```
vector<string> lines;
```

One last thing (less important) is the fact that you read 7 lines from the file. What if the file has 4 lines or maybe 56 lines? So, here's what you should really do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main () {

   std::vector<std::string> lines;
   std::ifstream infile("names.txt");

   std::string line;
   while(std::getline(infile, line)) {
      lines.push_back(line);
      std::cout << lines.back() << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```